# Returning the month index/number instead of month name

Tags: python, tkinter, return

```
self.months = ('January', 'February', 'March',
                        'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
                        'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')

self.option_var = tk.StringVar(self)

        # option menu
        option_menum = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var,
            self.months[0],
            *self.months,
            )

birth_month = self.option_var.get()
```

so, I'm programming an age calculator in python + tkinter and I'm wondering if instead of returning the month name ("Jan"...), I can return a number, or rather the month's index in the list.

Comment: Is `birth_month = self.months.index(self.option_var.get())` what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making `self.months` a list?

```
self.months = ['January', 'February', 'March',
                        'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
                        'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

and then use .index(), e.g.

```
month_you_are_looking_for = "March"

month_as_integer = self.months.index(month_you_are_looking_for)+1
```

As @h4z3 pointed out in the comments, the same works if you want to use your months in a tuple, as you originally did!

Comment: Why make it a list, when tuple also offers index method? List is mutable, tuple here is a better choice

Comment: @h4z3 I agree with you, that works as well. But since Red used the term "list" in the question, I went for this format.

Comment: OP used the term "list" but their code used tuples, which are a) objectively better and b) less modification to OP's code

Comment: my bad, didn't even realize i used the wrong term. either way works, thank you!